# How can I create a tool tip that behaves as a window?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

So I want to have a tool tip that remains open until I press the x button at the top right of the small tool tip.
Even if I'm clicking somewhere else or writing on the page I need it to remain open.
I haven't figured out a way to do it with tool tip or mat-tooltip, nor have I found examples online.
Maybe there's another component that I don't know of.

I want to add this inside a dialog modal. I'm not sure if it's relevant or not, but I've had issues with normal tool tips inside modals before.

Comment: have to create a custom component that act as tooltip

Comment: @prashant really? Sounded like a common concept. I've seen it used on other websites before. It also doesn't have to be material angular.

Comment: Yes, only difference would be then you need to hide it on some button click instead of on blur

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try creating a custom tooltip which close only on clicking the x button.

Cutom one with position absolute, i mean